# does stutter only refer to speech?

Tags: dictionaries

Can an action be stuttered? Or is it only referring to talking only? I see in the dictionary that it means to speak in such a way that the rhythm is interrupted by repetitions. What if an action is interrupted by repetitions? would that also be considered stutter?

Comment: I know of no rule that forbids the use of stutter more widely, as in **the engine stuttered to a halt** or **stuttered into life**.

Comment: Stutter is mostly used in describing speech but can be used in describing any short, repetitive sound or action.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stutter) provides the best response to this question. They provide two distinct meanings: the first relates to speech, and the  second is

> to work or happen in a way that is not smooth or regular

Regarding the sentence in your comment to Lars Mekes' answer:

> He stuttered the ball, that's why they lost. - *incorrect*

This doesn't work for two reasons. First, when stutter is applied to a person, the first meaning would take precedence. Second, **the ball** is the object of the verb **stutter**: if you check the dictionary, **stutter** is intransitive, and so it cannot take an object. Nor could you say "the ball stuttered", because a ball cannot "work or happen".

Answer (score 0):

[Stutter](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stutter) is not restricted to speech. It can also be used to indicate a series of short, sharp sounds or a progress that is not going smoothly.

Comment: So can I say "he stuttered the ball, that's why they lost."?

Comment: His stuttering performance with the ball led to their loss.

Answer (score 0):

"Herky jerky" is the informal phrase used to indicate start and stop actions.

Haltingly would be the adverb most like stutter.  "He haltingly threw the ball around."

Comment: Is there a formal phrase?

Comment: Just to note that herky-jerky is [American English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/herky-jerky) and probably unknown in the UK, and possibly other places.

Answer (score 0):

Hm.  You *can* use stuttering to refer to actions other than speech, but there's always an implicit analogy to speech lurking in the connotations. One wouldn't say "He stuttered the ball".  That sounds really strange because stuttered doesn't take an object -- it refers reflexively to its own subject.  Some of the other suggestions here work so well because they are referring to sounds, so the phrase "the engine stuttered to life" tells us that it banged and clattered and almost describes the vocalizations of a living creature.  If you search the internet for the phrase "stuttered across" you'll find that most of the times that phrase is used, the author is referring to sounds, breaths, exhalations, vocalizations, or at least is metaphorically describing an inanimate thing as though it is alive.

Answer (score 0):

While stutter can be used to refer to non-speech actions, it is uncommon in my experience. The most common variants I've encountered are "stuttering steps" in literature and the related "stutter step" movement as a tactic: [Merriam-Webster Stutter Step](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stutter%20step) . I've also seen machines described as moving in "stuttering jerks", using the definition that Dr. Gary posted from Merriam-Webster.

Answer (score -1):

> The rock stuttered across the lake.

From the [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stutter):

> 2 : to move or act in a halting or spasmodic manner.
>
> - *the old jalopy bucks and stutters uphill*